# Does Outlook web app support dark mode changes for manifest.xml?

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

We are building an outlook webapp add-in, and based on the user preferences trying to change the outlook read/compose surface commands icons. Is this currently supported ? If it's not, what is the suggested approach on, how to show two different icons in the command bar based on the selected color mode ?

Comment: I have a feature request for this open here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/office-add-in-manifest-overrides-for-dark-mode/idi-p/2884091

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the feature you requested is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins) page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.